# I want to uninstall Cygwin, but I don't have cygrunsrv

Tags: cygwin, uninstall

I want to uninstall Cygwin, but I don't have `cygrunsrv`. Can anyone help? I was trying to delete the folder and I might have deleted `cygrunsev`, which is what every website tells me I need in order to find its running services before I can delete the folder.

I've tried deleting with administrator privileges in the command prompt, nothing is working.
I tried to re-install it to figure out what to do, but that didn't work either.

EDIT:

When I run Cygwin I get the error `"/bin/bash: No such file or directory"`, and it's correct, in the Cygwin directory `/bin/` there is no `bash` directory, I've tried to add one, but it says I don't have permission, even when I use a command prompt with administrator privileges.

I tried reinstalling Cygwin and it gave me the error:

```
Package: base-files
    base-files-profile.sh exit code -6
    base-files-mketc.sh exit code -6
Package: cygutils
    cygutils.sh exit code -6
Package: man
    man.sh exit code -6
Package: Unknown package
    autorebase.bat exit code 1
    update-info-dir.sh exit code -6
```

and the previous error, no `bin/bash` is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is working"? What, specifically, are you doing, and what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have cygrunsrv, you don't need to stop or delete it. Just skip over the bits that talk about cygrunsrv and carry on with your uninstall.

You are following the [Cygwin FAQ uninstall instructions](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-all), right? Anything else is liable to be out of date and contain instructions like worrying about cygrunsrv that you actually don't need to care about.

Comment: When I run Cygwin I get the error "/bin/bash: No such file or directory", and it's correct, in the Cygwin directory /bin there is no /bash directory, I've tried to add one, but it says I don't have permission, even when I use a command prompt with administrator privileges. I tried reinstalling Cygwin and it gave me the error: Package: base-files base-files-profile.sh exit code -6 base-files-mketc.sh exit code -6
Package: cygutils cygutils.sh exit code -6
Package: man man.sh exit code -6
Package: Unknown package autorebase.bat exit code 1 update-info-dir.sh exit code -6 and the previous error,

Comment: @mathacka: Are you the OP? If not, you'll have better luck getting help by asking a new question than asking in a comment for help. In any case, first step is to completely delete your Cygwin install and start from scratch: delete your `C:\cygwin` directory entirely.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Comment: @Asad: Fixed that; looks like the layout of the Cygwin FAQs has changed since I originally wrote that answer. Thanks for the heads up!